# How to stop aiohttp server running in a thread?

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, aiohttp

I am working on UI app (kivy) and trying to implement python AIOHTTP Server start and stop buttons.
I have found example in another post how to start aiohttp server in a thread (main thread is used by UI app).
But not sure how to stop the aiohttp server running in a thread, as loop.run_forever is a blocking method.

Thanks in advance.

Python  3.7.0
aiohttp 3.6.2
OS: Windows

Code is:

**Serverthread.py**

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


def aiohttp_server():
    print("aiohttp_server runner created")

    async def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    return runner


def run_server(runner):
    print("Entering run_server")
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.setup())
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
    print("Loop run_forever")
    loop.run_forever()


def stop_server(runner):
    print("Entering stop_server")
```

App, my-ui.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

from serverthread import run_server, aiohttp_server
import threading


class ServerAdmin(Widget):
    active_threads = NumericProperty(0)
    t = ObjectProperty(threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(),), daemon=True))

    def start_server(self):
        if self.active_threads == 0:
            print("starting server...")
            self.t.start()
            self.active_threads += 1
            print("Server thread started.")

        else:
            print("Number of active threads: ", str(self.active_threads))

    def stop_server(self):
        print("stopping server...")
        print(f"Check if thread active: {str(self.t.isAlive())}, {self.t.name}")
        pass


class MyUiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ServerAdmin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyUiApp().run()
```

Comment: The loop has a [stop method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.stop). I think you can just  keep a reference to the loop, then call something like `self.loop.stop()`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comment. I have create new loop, in the main app (my-ui.py) as global variable and used in the Thread as argument:

```loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


class ServerAdmin(Widget):
    active_threads = BooleanProperty(False)

    # loop = ObjectProperty(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    t = ObjectProperty(threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(loop, aiohttp_server(),), daemon=True))
....

    def stop_server(self):
        if loop.is_running():
            loop.stop()
            self.active_threads = False

```

Comment: Just wondering if I have to do something else about [runner cleanup](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/web_advanced.html#application-runners) ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Share event

```
class ServerAdmin(Widget):
    stop = ObjectProperty(asyncio.Event())
    t = ObjectProperty(threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(),stop ), daemon=True))

    def stop_server(self):
        self.stop.set()


def run_server(runner, stop):
    ...
    print("Loop run_forever")
    # loop.run_forever()
    loop.run_until_complete(stop.wait())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Hi Eri, failed with
` Traceback (most recent call last):
....  
   loop.run_until_complete(stop.wait())
   File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
     return future.result()
   File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 293, in wait
     await fut
 RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<Event.wait() running at C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\locks.py:293> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:150]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`

note: in initializing the Thread, I had to use **self.stop**

Comment: can you run app in main loop? not `new_event_loop`, but `get_event_loop`

Comment: loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() -- able to get a loop, but seems that it is not running, not the same that is started in the thread/aiohttp server
print("loop running: ", loop.is_running()) -- loop running:  False.
If using loop = asyncio.get_running_loop(), throws RuntimeError: no running event loop

Comment: @John Anderson, suggestion to create a loop in main and then to close the loop is working. Not sure if there is a better way of doing as aiohttp server/tcpsite is not shutdown gracefully, I suspect. Might be wrong too.

Comment: Remark for future visitors: if Python Kivy is not used, `ObjectProperty` is not necessary. Instead, make it a normal object property (set in `__init__`) or variable.